# Cakephp redirect issue with nginx

Tags: nginx, cakephp-2.0

Hi can anyone help me solve the following issue:

I have a cakephp site hosted on Apache. The site works fine on Apache but moving it to nginx creates a redirect loop i.e. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Following is my nginx vhost configuration:

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name dev.site.com;
root   /var/www/html/site/app/webroot;
index  index.php;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }

location ~ \.php$ {
    #try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your config looks like mine, only diff I have ```listen 80;```and ```listen [::]:80;```.  But you run cakephp 2  @ php 7.3 ?

Comment: yes cakephp is 2.10 & php7.3